# How to position text blocks in a parent div?

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive

I have a problem with creating a responsive layout. I want to create a parent div, which will have a specified maximum width, e.g. 1200px and seven text blocks, which will be in it and will have a certain minimum width, e.g. 150px. The problem is in positioning the elements in the parent block, I would like to see four blocks of text in the first line in high resolution and three in the second line. At the resolution of the resolution in the first line there would be three text blocks, in the second line the same way and in the third one one text block. If you reduce the resolution again in the first, second and third line, there would be two text blocks and in the fourth one, etc. Please help.

Currently, I managed to write such a code:

```css
.parent{
    max-width: 1500px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid rgb(223, 113, 113);
    
}
.first, .third, .fifth, .seventh{
    background-color: rgb(248, 125, 77);
    border: 2px solid rgb(240, 85, 24);
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left; 
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 375px;
    margin: 16px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.second, .fourth, .sixth{
    background-color: rgb(102, 189, 247);
    border: 2px solid rgb(29, 154, 238);
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    max-width: 375px;
    min-width: 300px;
    margin: 16px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Responsive layout</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="first"></div>
        <div class="second"></div>
        <div class="third"></div>
        <div class="fourth"></div>
        <div class="fifth"></div>
        <div class="sixth"></div>
        <div class="seventh"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
.parent{
    width:1200px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(223, 113, 113);

}
.first, .third, .fifth, .seventh{
    background-color: rgb(248, 125, 77);
    border: 2px solid rgb(240, 85, 24);
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left; 
    margin: 16px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.second, .fourth, .sixth{
    background-color: rgb(102, 189, 247);
    border: 2px solid rgb(29, 154, 238);
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    margin: 16px;
    padding: 5px;
}


.first, .third, .fourth, .second{
    width: calc(25% - (3*15.5px));
}

.seventh, .fifth, .sixth{
    width: calc(100% / 3 - (3*15.5px));
}

@media all and (max-width: 1215px) {
    .parent{
        width: 95%;
    }
    .first, .third, .fourth, .second{
        width: calc(100% / 3 - (3*15.5px));
    }

    .fourth, .fifth, .sixth{
        width: calc(100% / 3 - (3*15.5px));
    }
    .seventh{
        width: 95%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's about something like that. I still have a question about divisions of the first, second, third, fourth, fifth, sixth and seventh, so they have a minimum width of 300px. How do you modify the code to make it work like on the image but have a set minimum width?

Comment: Just add: min-width: 300px; But if they have min width 300px, you can't have 16px margin, because your parent is 1200px, and 4*300 is 1200, so you don't have enough space for 4 divs.

Comment: + It gets 14 px from border-left 2px, border-right 2px, padding left 5px, padding right 5px, so if you want fix 300px divs, you need to set min width to 286px

Comment: I understand, thank you very much. In case of problems, I will write.